# Sorting nested arrays in Safari

Tags: javascript, sorting, safari

tldr: this question is about a specific edge case where a sort comperator returning -1, false or true, breaks only in Safari. This is different than all other similar questions concerning only values of false, true without -1.

I am trying to understand why Safari behaves differently for sorting a nested array by the first sub-element, with this specific "short-form" comparator:

`[[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1]].sort((a, b) => a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : a[0] > b[0])`

Chrome and Firefox give the expected result:

`[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]`

But Safari (15.1; which [should do stable sort](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_sort_stable)) gives:

`[[0, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0]]`

I know that the comparator function is supposed to return -1, 0, 1; And indeed the correct result is obtained on all browsers using the proper:

`(a, b) => a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : a[0] > b[0] ? 1 : 0`

But for the original "short-form" comparator, I expected the boolean result of `a[0] > b[0]` to be coerced into 0 and 1, as I assume is happening in Chrome and Firefox. Any insight why is Safari giving that result in that case?

Comment: [sort stability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#sort_stability) and [well-defined comparator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#sorting_with_non-well-formed_comparator), safari is always behind in implementing new features

Comment: @MisterJojo it should be the same and indeed gives the same result as without the brackets

Comment: If you want a shortcut, use `(a, b) => a[0] - b[0]`. The comparison function doesn't have to return `-1, 0, 1`, it can return any negative or positive numbers.

Comment: KonradLinkowski and @Barmar: As mentioned, the sort should be stable and I know about well-defined comparators. The question was why the boolean is not coerced to 0, 1 in Safari (assuming this is what is happening in the other browsers). I cannot use subtraction because it needs to work also for strings.

Comment: Deleted my answer, because you are right. You would probably need to read the source code to find out why

Comment: Safari has its own JS engine, and it's quirky.

Comment: @MisterJojo I think you have several typos and guess you mean the proper comparator mentioned last in my question

Comment: for string sort use localCompare() method

Comment: @MisterJojo I need something that works for both numbers and strings, and also the localCompare depends on the locale and I cannot have that.

Comment: @MisterJojo safari is supposed to do stable sort as mention in the link i've added. why do you say that the current behavior is correct? and why is it different from chrome/firefox?

Comment: whatever wrote caniuse.com, your tested Safari version doesn't seems to implement a stable sort.

Comment: @MisterJojo it does seem to be stable for the full comperator...

Comment: in this case, you must send an email to this site to show your test and that they correct their error. I also imagine that you have opened a report ticket on this bug with the Apple Safari team.